# Модификация данных через Мастер импорта SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет

Проблема в импорте данных на SQL Server 2008 R2 из эксель файла.

Задача такая, есть эксель файл (.xls), в нем две колонки, одна с датой в текстовом виде ('2015-01-01'), другая с неким числом.
Как мне ее засунуть в таблицу, где типы колонок (datetime2(7), decimal(10,0))?

Через стандартный мастер импорта экпорта SQL Server не получается, естественно загвоздка в дате, пробовал сам выбрать параметр "Написать запрос, указывающий данные для передачи", и написать что-то типа:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(7), arcdate) arcdate, my_number FROM `Лист1$`
```

В ответ ругань "Эта инструкция SQL не является запросом".
Простой запрос, без использования функций конвертации, проходит, типа такой:

```
SELECT arcdate + ' привет', my_number FROM `Лист1$`
```

И не важно какая функция, cast или convert. Я так понимаю преобразования он не поддерживает? Не хочется делать по старинке, загружать в тексте, потом запросом конвертировать в дату, думаю можно и сразу в дату.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Честно говоря, не думаю, что мой ответ был исчерпывающим, скорее - альтернативный вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать импортировать данные из Excel файла прямым запросом с помощью инструкции `openrowset`.

Через `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB` драйвер:

```
insert into targetTable(arcdate, my_number)
select
    cast(arcdate as datetime(7)) arcdate,
    cast(my_number as decimal(10,0)) my_number
from openrowset(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0;Database=d:\Data\File.xls;HDR=YES',
    ['Sheet name$'])
```

либо через `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB` драйвер:

```
insert into targetTable(arcdate, my_number)
select
    cast(arcdate as datetime(7)) arcdate,
    cast(my_number as decimal(10,0)) my_number
from openrowset(
    'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\Data\File.xls;HDR=YES',
    ['Sheet name$'])
```

смотря что у вас установлено. Думаю, что скорее всего мастер импорта что-то подобное и делает.

Обратите внимание, что можно написать так:

```
select *
from openrowset(
    'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\Data\File.xls;HDR=YES',
    ['Sheet name$'])
```

здесь последним параметром `openrowset` задаётся имя листа в xls файле. А можно так:

```
select *
from openrowset(
    'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\Data\File.xls;HDR=YES',
    'select * from [Sheet name$]')
```

здесь последний параметр `openrowset` уже SQL-запрос к данным xls файла.

Вероятно ваши

```
SELECT arcdate + ' привет', my_number FROM `Лист1$`
```

и

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(7), arcdate) arcdate, my_number FROM `Лист1$`
```

идут по второму варианту, т.е. запрос, который вы указываете идёт не к SqlServer, а к OLEDB, и первый нормально парсится OLEDB драйвером, а второй - нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Работаю с удаленным сервером, использовать openrowset или openquery к локальным файлам нет возможности. Нашел выход в том, что сохраняю файл в *.csv формате, потом колонкам даю свои форматы, например для даты "DT_DATE". [Тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms141704(v=sql.120).aspx) описаны все типы.

Comment: @scribe, можно скопировать файл на удалённый сервер, положить в определённую директорию, и указать путь к нему во втором параметре `openrowset`, если конечно есть права, и там сконфигурировано всё для того, чтобы связка openrowset + xls работала.

Comment: в том то и дело что нет прав залить файл непосредственно на сервер.